# Unable to find "ParallelMultiSearcher" and "Hits" class in lucene.Net 3.0.3.0 dll

Tags: c#, lucene, lucene.net

I m using latest dll of "Lucene.Net 3.0.3.0" in which i m unable to find "ParallelMultiSearcher" and "Hits" class which were previously present in "Lucene.Net 2.9.2". 
Can you please tell me how to use "parallerMultiSearcher" and "Hits" in "Lucene.Net 3.0.3.0" or is there any alternative for that?

Answer (score 0):

`Hits` was deprecated in 2.9, and removed in 3.0.  See the deprecation notes in the [`Searcher` documentation](http://lucene.apache.org/core/2_9_4/api/all/org/apache/lucene/search/Searcher.html#search%28org.apache.lucene.search.Query%29).  You'll need to change your calls to `searcher.search` to one that agrees with the changes to the API (which mostly just involves passing an extra arg specifying the maximum number of hits to return and handling the `TopDocs` object returned).

On [`ParallelMultiSearcher`](http://lucenenet.apache.org/docs/3.0.3/d6/dd3/class_lucene_1_1_net_1_1_search_1_1_parallel_multi_searcher.html), it's API is changed a bit, but it doesn't seem to have gone anywhere at that time.